# Visual studio 2017 unable to connect to TFS 2008 URL

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm unable to connect TFS 2008 URL from VS2017; Is there any patch or providers needs to be installed

Googled alot about **msscci provider**,

but there isn't anything specific for 2017!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I keep a blogpost with the most up-to-date information on which versions of Visual Studio connect to what and which things you need to have installed. [TFS 2008 has been out of support for a while now (April 2018)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/end-of-support-for-visual-studio-2008-in-one-year/) and Visual Studio 2017 can't connect to it anymore as a result. Team Explorer 2010 is the last version that officially supports connecting to this old TFS version.

In order to work with TFS 2008, you need Team Explorer 2010 or lower installed and use that for your interactions with TFS 2008. This does mean that you won't have any working Team Explorer or Source control integration in the Solution Explorer.

It's highly recommended to upgrade TFS 2008 to TFS 2018 or the soon to be released Azure DevOps Server 2019. Or, take away the maintenance burden of having to run your own servers, by migrating to Azure DevOps in the cloud. The process to migrate does require an intermediate upgrade to TFS 2018 though, so I'd start with that regardless.

What to download and install for:

- [Team Explorer 2010](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#te2010)

  - [Correct TE 2010 download location](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Team%20Explorer%202010&pgroup=)
- [Team Explorer 2008](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#te2008)